Language as we know it is a unique human property

Language as we know it is a unique human property.

'it' is an object of the verb 'know' or a subject?

"as we know it" could be understood as clausal adjunct, "language" being the antecedent of "it" and "it" the object of the verb know.

Sounds, as we hear them, are the result of waves traveling through  air (or water) and striking our ear drum.

There, "as we hear them" could be only partially paraphrased as "which we hear"; a relative clause wouldn't fully express the meaning.

OP's query:

Language as we know it is a unique human property.
'it' is an object of the verb 'know' or a subject?

In the sentence, the subordinate clause (adverbial clause of manner) is in the active voice and "it" is the object of the verb "know"" and we is the subject.
"It" is the pronoun for "language" in the main clause.
We can make "it" the subject by changing the subordinate clause into passive voice.
Language, as it is known (to us), is a unique human property.

'relative clause' has a case (subjective, possessive, and objective). Which case do you think is it?


Language (as we know it) is a unique human property.

The subject of the sentence is language.
It is the object of know.

Commas make the parse clear but you don't have to use them:

Language, as we know it, is a unique human property.

"it" is the direct object of the verb know.
